# Clear memory dump of API headers in android Cordova app

Tags: android, webview, dump, frida

While making an API request in an android application build using Angular and Cordova, headers are getting dumped in memory. These can be retrieved using Fridump. Tried clearing cookies, cache  and cleared the respective variables as well. But nothing is working out.

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, apps use RAM for building, processing and storing data. That is nothing unusual, hence I don't see what problem you are referring to.

Comment: yah.. But this is something raised as part of security review since the headers are visible in the dumbed data. So checking whether there is any solution for clearing that out.

Comment: IMHO using Cordova for a security relevant app is the major issue here. That the header data is available in RAM is true for every app. I would assume that the security review just used this as an example to show what you can do with Frida. The issue they really wanted to show is that the app has no counter measures against Frida. Hence the recommendation should be to buy an app protection system that includes and-debugging and anti-Frida measures.